# POST Spring Data REST não funciona com relacionamentos

Tags: java, web-service, rest, spring-boot

Estou com um projeto usando Spring Boot e Spring Data Rest para servir uma API Rest.

Quando estou servindo uma entidade sem relacionamentos, funciona sem problemas.

O problema é quando uso uma entidade com relacionamentos. Não consigo adicionar novas entidades via POST. Testei com meu aplicativo AngularJS e com extensões do Google Chrome como Yet Another REST Client mas o POST não adiciona a entidade corretamente. Ele edita um registro já existente causando confusão.

Segue o código:

```
@Entity
public class City {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private boolean capital;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=State.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "state_id")
    private State state;
    // getters e setters omitidos
}

@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = CityProjection.class)
public interface Cities extends PagingAndSortingRepository<City, Long>{

}
```

Caso necessário posto mais partes do código.
Ainda assim não sei o que fiz de errado ou deixei de fazer para que funcione corretamente.

Todas as consultas funcionam corretamente.

---

Fiz o seguinte teste, mandei um Request como POST com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
{
    "name": "Aparecida de Goiânia",
    "capital": false,
    "state": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Goiás",
        "initials": "GO"
    }
}
```

E recebi como retorno e o que aparece no banco de dados:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Goiás",
  "capital": false,
  "_links": {
    "self": {
       "href": "http://localhost:8080/rest/cities/1"
     },
    "city": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/rest/cities/1{?projection}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "state": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/rest/cities/1/state"
    }
  }
}
```

O mesmo acontece se eu adicionar `"id": null` na cidade.

Comment: Qual é o erro e como está a mensagem sendo enviada para o serviço?

Comment: Nenhum erro é apresentado. Porém os dados não são inseridos.

Comment: Hum, estranho. Normalmente nesses casos é escrito log - de acordo com o nível de log configurado - que não há o recurso mapeado, que a mensagem recebida é fora do padrão, etc. Enfim, bota pelo menos a mensagem que você tá testando, como disse que está editando um registro já existente, pode ser a mensagem que esteja errada (com id preenchido, por exemplo).

Comment: Alterei a pergunta com o retorno solicitado. No log, nada a mais aparece. Só o log da inicialização do tomcat (o que é normal).

Comment: Prezado, quando você envia no POST state_id ao invés de state e o valor 1, o que acontece? Se você enviar o post sem o state grava? O que ocorre se você mudar para Lazy? Fez esses testes? Na classe State, os atributos são de fato id, name e initials? Além disso tem os métodos de acesso?

Comment: Se eu passar o campo `state_id` ou não passar, grava, mas o campo `state_id`da tabela fica null. O json também busca `"state": null`. Não testei com Lazy por se tratar apenas das consultas. E sim, as entidades tem todos os métodos de acesso públicos (getters e setters).

Comment: Testei também sem o Eager, a falta dele não atrapalhou nas consultas e isso é bom, mas ainda assim não funciona o POST. testei também com nomes de campos únicos com o `@Column` sem sucesso. Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Eu estava com um problema parecido e utilizei  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH) para evitar esses "Updates".  Coloca ai e vê no que dá.

Comment: Fiz os testes com o `CascadeType.REFRESH`, mas sem sucesso. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você deve fazer o post em State e depois em City enviando em state o endereço correspondente. (Não encontrei nenhuma forma de enviar o state como um objeto filho)

Exemplo:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/states
{ 
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Goiás",
  "initials": "GO"
}

POST http://localhost:8080/cities
{
  "name": "Aparecida de Goiânia",
  "capital": false,
  "state": "http://localhost:8080/states/1"
}

POST http://localhost:8080/cities
{
  "name": "Aparecida de Goiânia 2",
  "capital": false,
  "state": "http://localhost:8080/states/1"
}
```

Resposta ao chamar GET http://localhost:8080/cities

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "cities" : [ {
      "name" : "Aparecida de Goiânia",
      "id" : 1,
      "state" : {
        "name" : "Goiás",
        "initials" : "GO"
      },
      "capital" : false,
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/cities/1"
        },
        "city" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/cities/1{?projection}",
          "templated" : true
        },
        "state" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/cities/1/state"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "name" : "Aparecida de Goiânia 2",
      "id" : 2,
      "state" : {
        "name" : "Goiás",
        "initials" : "GO"
      },
      "capital" : false,
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/cities/2"
        },
        "city" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/cities/2{?projection}",
          "templated" : true
        },
        "state" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/cities/2/state"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/cities"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/cities"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 2,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Desculpa a demora para responder. Você diz para eu enviar o link no post ao invés do objeto em si? Farei os testes aqui sobre isso.

Comment: isso mesmo, pelos meus testes funcionou e foi a unica forma que consegui

Comment: Fiz os testes aqui e funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado! Só não precisa do POST em States antes pois já tenho o cadastro dos Estados (States) prontos.